# I want to check the output of multiple files by typing a single command

Tags: linux, bash, cluster-ssh

```
(directory=$(python -c 'import read_params; print(read_params.get_directory())')
nsrc=$(cat $directory/master.pixels|wc -l)
tail $directory/forward_src0{1..$nsrc}_ls00/out_data_forward)
```

What the above does is that a simulation is running (what that is is not important) and the above command tracks it, by printing out the files in the directory:

- ..../forward_src01_ls01/out_data_forward
- ..../forward_src01_ls02/out_data_forward
- ..../forward_src01_ls03/out_data_forward
- ..../forward_src01_ls04/out_data_forward

and so on till src_08.

It runs in some linux systems without error. But in my system, it throws  the below error:

```
[prasad@daahpc1 sparc_flows]$ (directory=$(python -c 'import read_params; print(read_params.get_directory())')
> nsrc=$(cat $directory/master.pixels|wc -l)
> tail $directory/forward_src0{1..$nsrc}_ls00/out_data_forward)
tail: cannot open /scratch/prasad/sparc_test/forward_src0{1..8}_ls00/out_data_forward' for reading: No such file or directory
```

To be clear, these files do exist... I can open them individually, but not in a batch.

Comment: Bash does not do `{1..$nsrc}`.  The system you are using where this works may be using `ksh93` or `zsh`, but it would not be `bash`.

Comment: Welcome. It looks like you have an interesting question, but I can't understand it, others may misunderstand. Please proof-read and improve. (A clear question will result in better answers).

Comment: I am using bash. I did echo $SHELL. And it said /bin/bash. In my local system and in the cluster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell in your systems seems to be different from the ones you used on the other systems (`echo $SHELL`)

Your local shell is not understanding/replacing the `{1..8}` on your `tail` call.

Try using the same shell on your system, also you can use the `*` universal wildcard instead in your script in case `{1..8}` can be replaced safely by `*`

Comment: I am using bash in both my local system and in the cluster

Comment: `bash` does not do brace expansions with variable ranges. `{1..8}` would not have been a problem.